# pyGithub maximum use of API call rate

Tags: python, github-api, pygithub

I am attempting to use the pyGithub library for accessing v3 API of github. Although this library is simple to use. I found the documentation to be very vague.

Below I am successfully getting the contents of a file with the file path and its sha. My end goal is to reduce my API calls from 3 to just 1, since I want to make use of the full 5000 API calls within the hour.

```
from github import Github
gh = Github(access_token) # I supply an access token here.
user = gh.get_user(owner_name) # This takes 1 API call
repo = user.get_repo(repo_name) # This takes 1 API call


file = repo.get_file_contents(filename, ref=sha) # This takes 1 API call
```

Does anyone know how I can pass the repo and owner name to get_file_contents() or a similar function I can use to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce it from 3 API calls to just 2 by using get_repo() with the format 'owner_name/repo_name'

```
from github import Github
gh = Github(access_token) # I supply an access token here.
repo = gh.get_repo(owner_name+'/'+repo_name) # This takes 1 API call

file = repo.get_file_contents(filename, ref=sha) # This takes 1 API call
```

Just mentioning this here for future reference. In actuality I ended up using the requests library and forming my own api calls.

Like This:

```
import requests
# Import python's base64 decoder
from base64 import b64decode as decode

def GET(owner_repo,filename,sha,access_token):
    # Supply Headers
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization':'token '+access_token}
    # This function is stable so long as the github API structure does not change. 
    # Also I am using the previously mentioned combo of owner/repo.
    url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/%s/contents/%s?ref=%s' % (owner_repo, filename, sha)
    # Let's stay within the API rate limits
    url_rate_limit = 'https://api.github.com/rate_limit'
    r = requests.get(url_rate_limit, headers=headers)
    rate_limit = int(r.json()['resources']['core']['remaining'])
    if(rate_limit > 0):
        # The actual request
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        # Note: you will need to handle the any error codes yourself. 
        # I am just safe checking for '200' OK
        if(r.status_code == 200):
            content = r.json()['content']
            # Decode base64 content
            decoded_content = decode(content)
            return decoded_content
```

I license the above code under the MIT license.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know how I can pass the repo and owner name to get_file_contents()

Given the [current implementation of `get_file_contents`](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/1c0fd97d7d18f16b489830dd3437ab51d4258636/github/Repository.py#L1481-L1497), it expects:

- either a GithubObject (which costs API calls)
- or a string (which does not cost API calls)

But both depends on a [class Repository](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/1c0fd97d7d18f16b489830dd3437ab51d4258636/github/Repository.py#L142), which does involve API calls.
So if you can make your process a long-lived one, able to reuse within a single execution session that repository, that would be best.

But if you have to get files from *multiple* repos, that won't help.

Comment: I ended writing my own API caller. That can do this in one API call.

Comment: @XChikuX Great! Do you have a link to an open-source version of that API caller?

Comment: I haven't commited it online anywhere. I'll just include it in my answer. Feel free to make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub API supports [conditional requests](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#conditional-requests), and cache hits do not count against the rate limit:

> Making a conditional request and receiving a 304 response does not count against your Rate Limit, so **we encourage you to use it whenever possible**.

However, PyGithub does not implement caching:

https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/issues/585

It is, however, possible in GitHub3:

https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py/issues/75#issuecomment-128345063

There are some packages which add caching to Requests:

- There is [requests-cache](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide.html), which has a global patching mechanism, but it [does not yet support HTTP preconditions](https://github.com/reclosedev/requests-cache/issues/332)
- There is [cachecontrol](https://github.com/ionrock/cachecontrol), which does not have a global patching mechanism, but I managed to integrate it with PyGithub by patching some internals:

```py
gh = github.Github(token)
class CachingConnectionClass(gh._Github__requester._Requester__connectionClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(gh._Github__requester._Requester__connectionClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.session = CacheControl(self.session,
                                    cache=FileCache('.github-cache'))
gh._Github__requester._Requester__connectionClass = CachingConnectionClass
```